# Modelling data based on a time range using redux/normalizr

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalizr

I've have the following data coming from a node backend:

Endpoint:

`/user/:id?startDate=2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z&endDate=2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z`

```
[
   {
      "name": "Tom",
      "createdAt": "2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z",
      ...
      "metadata": {
         "activeHours": 134.45,
         "afkHours": 134.45
      }
   },
   {
      ...
   }
]
```

In this data, the only thing modified between date changes is activeHours and afkHours.

These users and the date that the endpoint was called with must be synced across all pages.

The simple approach would be to put this in a users reducer, something like:

```
{
   users: [...],
   startDate: "",
   endDate: ""
}
```

However I'm currently using normalizr with these users and with that I have a single action named `ADD_ENTITIES`. Having an entities reducer seems very beneficial as we do have other entities that can be nicely normalized with these users, however I don't want to pollute the entities state with almost "tacked on" startDate and endDate to sync across all pages.

On to my question:

### Is there a better way to model this problem using normalizr, Where your key is not only ID but also a date range?

Or should I look at breaking this out into a separate reducer as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I completely understood the problem here.

Is the `startDate` and `endDate` fields, different for each user ? If yes, then you may need to add those fields in the normalized entity object for those users.

If those are common fields for all the users, you can create a separate entity called `userDateRange` containing those two keys. It doesn't need to be normalized as they are primitive fields.

```
{
  "entities": {
    "user": {
      "byId": {
        "user1": {},
        "user2": {}
      },
      "allIds": [
        "user1",
        "user2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "ui": {
    "userDateRange": {
      "start": "2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z",
      "end": "2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you've understood it! Sorry, should have been clearer, It's the same for all users, each time we select a new date range in the picker, it must make the call again and update the normalized users. But that's a good shout, the only problem is, in which reducer ddo I put the `userDateRange`?

Comment: Updated the answer with an example state shape.

As the selected date values do not come from server and are more like user specific inputs, you could keep them outside entities. Say in another block called `ui`. I usually separate the server side ( API responses ) and client side (form state, filters) entities to different reducers to keep it simple.

If you are using a 3rd party form library such as `redux-form` this will be done automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I guess my only concern is that by doing that I'm detaching the start and end date from the machine state and to me I see them as very much attached to that state? Maybe I'm overthinking the problem and I may very well go with this. Thanks again!

Comment: One reason for keeping them separate is, lets say tomorrow the same dateRange is required to fetch some other entities too.

Hence instead of creating a separate copy for that, this can be reused. Again this is specific for the app, and there is no perfect answer.

Comment: Very true! I'll accept this as I think you're right :)